# What does "Make the colours in the sky" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, songs

> Ay, ay, ay
>
> I'm your little butterfly
>
> Green, black and blue
>
> Make the colours in the sky

Source: https://genius.com/Smiledk-butterfly-lyrics

Or as song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzcvRDWgRIE&t=37s

Does it mean that green, black and blue make up the colours of the sky? Or do they mean that the butterfly is green, black and blue? If the latter, why not "Like the" instead of "Make the"?

Comment: In my opinion the lyrics alone do not make it clear what the song's writer(s) intended. Perhaps they want listeners to make up their own minds about what it means to them.

Comment: I agree with @nnnnnn and I think you'll be luckier if you ask at Genius rather than here.

Answer (score 0):

I've watched the video from youtube, Veronica Almqvist and Nina Boquist were singing this song. Possibly from a woman's perspective, who is searching for her dream man or metaphorically referring him as **samurai**. However, the woman or girl is being compared with **butterfly**, I guess it's being used as a metaphor of natural beauty. This beauty is accompanied by colors, like, green, black & blue. Now, we know that, rainbows can occur in sky, **VIBGYOR** is the sequence usually, where you will find green & blue. However, the color **black** may purport **black sky** or cloudy sky. I think the songwriter is trying to say, there may be some ugliness, loathsomeness, un-beautifulness even when we are searching beauty in something.